# Getting a value of input field in a React component

Tags: reactjs

Just learning React and I have seen various different ways to get a value from a text input. I wanted ask whether all of them are correct or if there are any advantages to using one over another.

Method 1):

```
MyForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: ""
        };
    },
    onSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            username: this.refs.username.getDOMNode().value
        });
        /* Do something... */
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} id="login-form">
                    <input type="text" ref="username"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Method 2):

```
MyForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: ""
        };
    },
    handleUsernameChange: function(evt) {
        this.setState({
            username: evt.target.value
        });
    },
    onSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* Do something... */
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} id="login-form">
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: both are ok, I use the 2nd option. With react you don't need the forms as the are. You can have an input, then set the state with the user input, and with whatever element you want onclick event, take the components state, and make an ajax request with the user input.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, if you had a large form of say 100 elements (and you wanted to monitor their state), you would create 100 different 'handleChange' functions?

Comment: well that would depend on if there are 100 different actions that effect those elements, you should keep them all in state, and abstract away as much as possible. That said, the whole point of react is small components, so if you're doing that...well, its not good.

Comment: Lets say there are five elements in this component, it seems arduous to have to right five functions to handle each change and save the state. Could there simply not be a generic funtion that monitors changes and saves the state in an object/array?

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is the preferred way of handling inputs. Method 1 is an antipattern. My workplace uses a lint rule that explicitly forbids `getDOMNode()`. When using forms and/or refs, it may become difficult or sometimes even impossible to retrieve values from complex input fields such as custom dropdown components offered by frontend libraries.

Using `onChange` props to keep track of the state is more homogenous across different input fields and allows for easier transition into redux or similar technologies.

When there are many elements that need to have their values tracked, you're correct in that it is not advisable to write a handler function for each of them. You can write a higher order generic function. For example instead of

```
handleUsernameChange: function(evt) {
    this.setState({
        username: evt.target.value
    });
}
```

You could have a generic

```
handleChange: field => evt => {
    this.setState({
        [field]: evt.target.value
    });
}
```

And as your `onChange` prop you'd have `this.handleChange('username')`